# Use pipe symbol as separator in statusline

Tags: statusline

I wanted to make my own status line and I wonder how can I use a pipe as a separator? I want to achieve something like this:

`NORMAL | file.html                 [html] | utf-8 | 80:10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a pipe, escape it with double `\\|`:

```
func! VimMode() abort
    let md = mode()
    if md == 'n'
        return 'NORMAL'
    elseif md == 'v'
        return 'VISUAL'
    else " check mode() help to define other mode names here
        return 'OTHER'
    endif
    
endfunc

set statusline=%{VimMode()}\ \\|
set statusline+=\ %f
set statusline+=%<
set statusline+=%=
set statusline+=%y
set statusline+=\ \\|\ %{&enc}
set statusline+=\ \\|\ %c:%l
```

[image]